# Kubuntu 22.04 won't suspend when on fully charged battery and lid closed

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, laptop

I have a Thinkpad X1C Gen 5 which has been working reliably with various versions of Kubuntu so far. But a few days ago I upgraded to 22.04, and the sleep when on battery and lid closed behaviour stopped working.

I played around a little, and it seems that

- sleep is still working fine (when invoked directly)
- lid close detection is working fine.

It looks like that **when the battery is fully (=100%) charged**, then even if I disconnect the power cord **the system still thinks that it is on AC power**, because it invokes the action configured for lid close on AC (I changed this to Sleep and the laptop went to sleep alright).

Is this a problem with the new kernel (5.15) or the new KDE (5.24)? Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Charge battery to full (=100%, even 99% won't trigger this)
2. Disconnect power cord (USB-C)
3. Close the lid

Expected: lid close action on battery triggered.
What happens instead: lid close action on AC power triggered.

Workaround: set charge limit to 99%. Luckily this is a Thinkpad... where this setting is available.

UPDATE: of course, after writing this post I tried to close the lid again... 99% and no sleep. So back to square 1. What is this?

Comment: I have same problem still